# How to prove that $\det A=|\lambda|^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be  a non-zero linear transformation on a real vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ .Let $V_0$ be the subspace of $V$ which forms the image of $V$ under $A$. Let $k=\dim V_0<n$ and suppose that for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ ;$A^2=\lambda A$. Then show that $\det A=|\lambda|^n$  and there is a non-trivial subspace $V_t\subset V$ such that $Ax=0$ for all $x\in V_t$

**My try:**
Since $A^2=\lambda A$ so the annihilating polynomial of $A$ is $x^2-\lambda x=0\implies x=0,\lambda $ which are the only eigen values of $A$.

Also since $\dim V_0<n$ Hence by rank-nullity theorem $\dim Null(A)>1$ and hence here is a non-trivial subspace $V_t\subset V$ such that $Ax=0$ for all $x\in V_t$.

But will not $\det A=0$ ? But we are given to prove that 
$\det A=|\lambda|^n$.
Is the question wrong or my solution?

Comment: Test you conclusion with $A=I$ identity and $\lambda=1$. The eigenvalues of the identity are not $x=0,1$, as you have claimed.

Comment: You are right that $\dim V_0<\dim V$ implies that $A$ is singular.

Comment: $A^2=\lambda A$, so $\det(A^2)=\det(\lambda A)=|\lambda|^n\det(A)$, divide both sides by $\det(A)$...

Comment: (only if $\det A\ne0$)

Comment: Where is this question from? I have to agree that it seems incorrect, because the fact that $A$ isn't an automorphism of $V$ would seem to imply that 0 is an eigenvalue and thus that the determinant is 0. If $k$ were not strictly less than $n$ it would make sense, as @KennyLau showed.

Comment: Thank you very much for asserting my claim @HagenvonEitzen

Answer (score 0):

Define

$$A:\Bbb R^4\to\Bbb R^4\;,\;\;A(x,y,z,w)^t:=(2x,2y,2z,0)^t\implies V_0=\{(x,y,z,0)\in\Bbb R^4\}\cong\Bbb R^3$$

Observe that

$$A^2(x,y,z,w)^t:=A(2x,2y,2z,0)^t:=(4x,4y,4z,0)^t=:2A(x,y,z,w)^t$$

yet $\;\det A=0\neq2^4\;$ since $\;A\;$ is singular and thus zero is one of its eigenvalues.